# Can I change the header color in html without using CSS?

Tags: html

I'm making a website without using anything other than html and headers can't be seen on the screen because of the background. So, I wanted to make them white instead of black. Can I do it without using anything besides html?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are avoiding CSS?

Comment: Yes with Javascript.

Comment: Hi, the default text/heading color is black. to change the color you will need to use css, you can use simple inline code like this > style="color:red;" <

Comment: It's a semester project and there is a rule says "use only html"

Comment: My English is a little bad. Sorry if I couldn't explain it well

Comment: I would check with whoever is running your course whether CSS is allowed. Inline styles are the only option for "HTML only" and are generally not good practice.

Comment: why is'nt the black text visible? the default background is white,

Comment: @JanKees I changed it and it was darker than I expected

Comment: I was curious about "is there a way to do it" and it seems the answer is "no." Thanks for the help! I'll just change the background with a lighter one :D

Comment: @hll_krts how did you change it? what did you use

Comment: @JanKees just used " background="" " in <body> and it worked. I remember it's something in html

Comment: @hll_krts thats called inline css, if you are allowed to use that i suggest > <h1 style="color:white"> your heading </h1>

Comment: @JanKees I think we're allowed use "<font color="">". Is this CSS? I'm a bit new to html. 

And I got warned about "avoiding extended discussions in comments." It'd be better if we discuss this in chat. Probably.

Comment: @hll_krts The `<font>` tag has been obsolete for many years. Do not use it.

Answer (score 0):

To change the colour  without using CSS just use the color and background-color of style attribute in html .I have attached an sample code for your reference.
Refer the link to understand more on styles.
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_styles.asp

```html
<html>
<header style="background-color:black">
Header
</header>
<p>content</p>
</html>
```

Comment: That's CSS even though you put it inside the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```html
<html>
<header style="background-color:black; color:white">
Header
</header>
<p>content</p>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure if my teacher accepts it. I used <font></font> instead. Looks more html.

Comment: That's still CSS.